# Is there any way to improve the space complexity of the following code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, space-complexity

I wrote this code on leetcode and I am not able to improve the space complexity of the following code without changing to bfs, which is turing out to be slower. I have to create a deep copy of a graph in the question, and all the values of the graph are unique and graph has no loops and is connected and undirected in nature.

[Link to Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/clone-graph/description/)

My approach to the problem is fairly simple being I will make a map, which will contain the original node int value with the new node associated with it. Then, I will check if it already has a value. If yes, end recursion. If no, apply bfs to that part as well.

I wrote the following code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

// Definition for a Node. Given by the task.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> neighbors;
    Node() {
        val = 0;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val, vector<Node*> _neighbors) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = _neighbors;
    }
};

class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map <int, Node*> mp;
    Node* dfs(Node *node){
        if(mp.find(node->val) != mp.end()) return mp[node->val];
        mp[node->val] = new Node(node->val);
        for(Node* &i : node->neighbors) mp[node->val]->neighbors.emplace_back(dfs(i));
        return mp[node->val];
    }
    Node* cloneGraph(Node* node) {
        if(!node) return nullptr;
        return dfs(node);
    }
};
```

I got 100% on time, and got 65% on space. Is there any way I can furthur optimize this answer to get a better space complexity?

Comment: Don't count on links to offsite resources. They may not always be available and eventually they rot. If the question cannot be understood without the information at the link, assume the question will be incomplete. You can usually fix this pretty easily by summarizing the important content at the link in the question.

Comment: Have you asked at leetcode itself, this is an algorithm issue not a C++ one. Leetcode will not teach you how to use C++ in a good way anyway (mostly bad practices to be honest). The one thing you are doing is using new, where a move would do too.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to improve the space complexity since you need the `unordered_map` to keep track of nodes that you've already seen. As such, the best space complexity possible is `O(n)` here where `n` is the number of nodes in the graph.